# two different definitions of associated primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a <s>finitely generated</s> (not required) module over a Noetherian ring $R$. I've learned two definitions of associated primes:

1. $P\subset R$ is an associated prime ideal of $M$ if $P$ is the annihilator of some element of $M$.
2. $P\subset R$ is an associated prime of $M$ if it is the generic point of an irreducible component of the support in $\operatorname{Spec}R$ of some $m\in M$.

The second definition seems to be the same as saying $P$ is minimal among primes containing the annihilator of $m$.  This makes it very close, but not quite the same as the first definition.

**If P is minimal over the annihilator of some $m$, why must $P$ be precisely the annihilator of some $m'$?**

Comment: Weakly Associated + Noetherian Ring $\implies$ Associated; see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/058A).

Comment: @user26857 perfect. thanks.